# Material UI - hierarchical ordered list

Tags: reactjs, list, material-ui

I wanted to do a simple list like this:

```
1. xxxxx
2. xxxxx
   a. xxxxx
   b. xxxxx
3. xxxxx
4. xxxxx
   a. xxxxx
   b. xxxxx
```

The contents is taken from a react state variable and be mapped to create this list.  The state variable structure is not decided upon yet.

If I used css ol & li, it looks straightforward.  But when I look at the MUI List, it does not seem to support this.  I have to create the numbering 1,2,3 and a,b,c manully.

Is there any MUI components that does a similar job as the css ul & li ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by using some CSS properties. First the `ListItem` this needs to have a `sx={{ display: "list-item" }}`. Then we can add `sx={{ listStyle: "decimal" }}` to the `List`

We also need to add some `padding-left` to be able to see the indicator, you can play with this.

```js
<List sx={{ listStyle: "decimal", pl: 4 }}>
  <ListItem sx={{ display: "list-item" }}>
    <ListItemText primary="A" />
  </ListItem>
  <ListItem sx={{ display: "list-item" }}>
    <ListItemText primary="List" />
  </ListItem>
  <ListItem sx={{ display: "list-item" }}>
    <ListItemText primary="Item" />
  </ListItem>
</List>
```

And use `listStyle: "lower-alpha"` for `a b c`