# Material UI - How to style the list marker using sx props?

Tags: reactjs, list, material-ui

Follow up question from : [Material UI - hierarchical ordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75857187/material-ui-hierarchical-ordered-list)

In material ui, if I have such a list with markers,

```
<List sx={{ listStyle: "decimal", pl: 4 }}>
  <ListItem sx={{ display: "list-item" }}>
    <ListItemText primary="A" />
  </ListItem>
  <ListItem sx={{ display: "list-item" }}>
    <ListItemText primary="List" />
  </ListItem>
  <ListItem sx={{ display: "list-item" }}>
    <ListItemText primary="Item" />
  </ListItem>
</List>

1. xxxxx
2. xxxxx
   a. xxxxx
   b. xxxxx
3. xxxxx
4. xxxxx
   a. xxxxx
   b. xxxxx
```

How do I style the marker using sx and scss ?  eg change the font, color, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question contains css with **sx** and demonstrates how to apply styles using sx:

```
sx={{
  display: "list-item",
  fontFamily: "Calibri",
  color: "#ff0000
}}
```

The [MUI docs](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/) have examples on how to use sx.

To use **scss**, import it into the file that uses the styles:

`import './styles.scss';`

A bundler like Webpack needs a [special loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/) to read scss files into JavaScript.

The selectors (IDs, classes, etc.) used in the scss match those in the JSX tags by using the `id` and `className` JSX attributes:

`<ListItem id="someId" className="someGlobalClassName" sx={{ display: "list-item" }}>`

To avoid repeating css definitions or applying class names on each tag you can target MUI components directly by using their **Global class names**. For example, the `<ListItem>` tag uses `.MuiListItem-root` to apply styles to the root element. Global class names are listed on the [API page](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/list-item/#css) for components.

## UPDATE

Note that using standard css *By default, it is not possible to change the bullet color of a list item.* --[w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_bullet_color.asp). Such changes require pseudo-element hacks like this (as demonstrated on the w3schools.com page):

```
ul li::before {
    content: '\u2022'; // Bullet character
    color: ...;
    font-family: ...;
    ...
}
```

Standard css properties for `list-style` are: `list-style-image`, `list-style-position`, and `list-style-type`. A list marker color property does not exist.

As markers, Material-UI Lists use components such as icons, avatars, images and checkboxes. The **sx prop** is applied to these components as it would be applied to any other MUI component. However, if you are looking to employ pseudo-element hacks to apply styles to standard-looking markers you can try the code below.

This sample code displays two lists. The first uses bullets. The second uses a decimal list type.

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MUI List sample</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="data:;">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=1">
        <script defer src="index.js"></script></head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <noscript> Please enable javascript to view the page</noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

### app.jsx

```
/**
 * Modified Basic List example from MUI docs.
 * Compiled into a bundle saved as index.js.
 *
 * @see https://mui.com/material-ui/react-list/#basic-list
 */
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import InboxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Inbox';
import DraftsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Drafts';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Box sx={ { width: '100%', maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: 'background.paper' } }>
            <nav aria-label="main mailbox folders">
                <List
                    sx={ {
                        [`& li.MuiListItem-root::before`]: {
                            content: "'\u2022'", // Bullet character
                            color: 'red',
                            fontFamily: 'Segoe UI'
                        }
                    } }
                >
                    <ListItem disablePadding>
                        <ListItemButton>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <InboxIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
                        </ListItemButton>
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem disablePadding>
                        <ListItemButton>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <DraftsIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary="Drafts" />
                        </ListItemButton>
                    </ListItem>
                </List>
            </nav>
            <Divider />
            <nav aria-label="secondary mailbox folders">
                <List
                    sx={ {
                        [`& li.MuiListItem-root`]: {
                            display: 'list-item',
                            listStyleType: 'decimal',
                            marginLeft: '1em'
                        },
                        [`& li.MuiListItem-root::marker`]: {
                            width: '1em',
                            fontFamily: "'Palatino Linotype'",
                            fontSize: '24px',
                            color: 'red'
                        }
                    } }
                >
                    <ListItem disablePadding>
                        <ListItemButton>
                            <ListItemText primary="Trash" />
                        </ListItemButton>
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem disablePadding>
                        <ListItemButton component="a" href="#simple-list">
                            <ListItemText primary="Spam" />
                        </ListItemButton>
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem>
                        <ListItemText primary="A" />
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem>
                        <ListItemText primary="List" />
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem>
                        <ListItemText primary="Item" />
                    </ListItem>
                </List>
            </nav>
        </Box>
    );
}


const container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    container
);
```

Comment: My question is how to style the *markers*, eg change the font, color... Can I style the marker ?

Comment: @EBDS Yes you can. See the update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't have the system with me for a few days.  When I can access, I'll test and accept.  Thanks again.

Comment: @EBDS Great. Those css definitions in **sx** can be updated dynamically too using [callbacks](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/#callback-values) that pass in the MUI **theme** object.